# Home Dashboard Screen Options always change

Tags: dashboard, debug, screen-options

Like any other WordPress user I have installed a few Themes and Plugins.

I recently noticed that the boxes on my Home Dashboard change every now and then and only 3 of them they are always there:

- Site Kit Summary
- Quick Stats
- Yoast SEO Posts Overview

[image]

I keep adding an putting back the boxes I want but days later everything switch back to these 3 boxes.

How can I debug this issue?

Is there any way I can have the logs of what and when has changed?

Comment: Do you share the account with somebody else?

Comment: @kero, no, I'm the only one

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem: there was a problem with the cache caused by the use of 3 plug-in at the same time

- Autoptimize
- LiteSpeed Cache
- W3 Total Cache

I have kept W3 Total Cache and disabled the first 2 and it's all good now